# Search and update something int he middle of an array with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, pdf, search

I have created an array with below code, now I wish that I can search within this array and can insert/delete/update something in the middle of this array. After some digging, I found that javascript only have push/pop, shift/unshift available to perform add and delete tasks. Please help me with what direct I should be looking at in my logic? Should I create something to sort my array and have the element I wish to modify to be the first or last of the order and perform add/delete, or if I wish to modify that element, I should first delete the old one, then add the new/updated one to the array? Please help me with code example that I should be looking at. Also I am currently working with PDF javascript API (Acrobat XI), where can I go to read something about the differences btw javascript and PDF javascript API? Because I notice that some of the codes are deemed syntax error by PDF javascript console, but it is working in console in chrome. For example code below: const result = str.split("\n").map(e => e.split("\t"));, in this line, the "=>" is not valid in PDF javascript console. Any information is much appreciated. Thank you.

```js
const str = `ADL    ADELAIDE, AU
AMS AMSTERDAM, NL
ATL ATLANTA, GA
BJS BEIJING, CN
BKK BANGKOK, TH
BLQ BOLOGNA, IT
BNE BRISBANE, AU
BOS BOSTON, MA
BWI BALTIMORE, MD
BWN BRUNEI, BN
CAN GUANGZHOU, CN
CLE CLEVELAND, OH
CLT CHARLOTTE, NC
CMH COLUMBUS, OH
CPH COPENHAGEN, DK
CPT CAPE TOWN, ZA
DCA WASHINGTON, DC
DEL DELHI, IN
DEN DENVER, CO
DFW FORT WORTH, TX
DLC DALIAN, CN
DRS DRESDEN, DE
DTW DETROIT, MI
EWR NEWARK, NJ
FLL FT. LAUDERDALE
FMO MUNSTER, DE
FRA FRANKFURT, DE
GUM GUAM, GU
HAM HAMBURG, DE
HGH HANGZHOU, CN
HKG HONG KONG, HK
HND HANEDA, JP
HNL HONOLULU, HI
IAD WASHINGTON, DC
IAH HOUSTON, TX
ICN INCHEON, KR
JED JEDDAH, SA
JFK NEW YORK, NY
KEF REYKJAVIK, IS
KUL KUALA LUMPUR,MY
LAS LAS VEGAS, NV
LAX LOS ANGELES , CA
LCK COLUMBUS, OH
LGA NEW YORK, NY
LHE LAHORE, PK
LHR LONDON, UK
LIS LISBON, PT
MCO ORLANDO, FL
MDW CHICAGO, IL
MEM MEMPHIS, TN
MIA MIAMI, FL
MNL MANILA, PH
MSP MINNEAPOLIS, MN
MSY NEW ORLEANS, LA
MUC MUNICH, DE
MXP MILAN, IT
NAN NADI, FJ
NRT NARITA, JP
OAK OAKLAND, CA
ORD CHICAGO, IL
PDX PORTLAND, OR
PEK BEIJING, CN
PHL PHILADELPHIA,PA
PHX PHOENIX, AZ
PIT PITTSBURGH, PA
PVG SHANGHAI, CN
RGN YANGON, MM
RUH RIYADH, SA
SAN SAN DIEGO, CA
SAT SAN ANTONIO, TX
SEA SEATTLE, WA
SFO SAN FRANCISCO
SGN HOCHIMINH CITY
SIN SINGAPORE, SG
STL ST. LOUIS, MO
SZX SHENZHEN, CN
TPA TAMPA, FL
TPE TAIPEI, TW
YUL MONTREAL, CA
YVR VANCOUVER, CA
YYZ TORONTO, CA`

const result = str.split("\n").map(e => e.split("\t"));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I would probably go with the default assumption that "PDF Javascript" doesn't support ES6 syntax.

Comment: That is what I am trying to find out as well. Please see below reading about Acrobat X (Mines XI). I don't know how is this going to be associate with ES5/ES6. I am looking for any help using the old codes.

Comment: So, the highest version of Javascript that Adobe's API supports is 1.6, in Acrobat 8 and up.  You will need to use 2005-style Javascript, so no arrow functions.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that James. Any help on the main topic?

Comment: You would use [Array.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to do the adding and removing.  You would use [Array.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to locate an element in the array.

Comment: Thank you James. Both works in PDF Javascript console, so I am going to look into these functions.

Comment: Hi James, it looks like Array.IndexOf does not work in 2D Array, it always reutnr -1, I think Array.splice is the same with 2D Arrays? Can you help come up with a solution? Thank you.

Comment: What are you looking up with indexOf, the airport code?

Answer (score 0):

Below is what I found out about PDF Javascript. I don't know how this is associating with ES5/ES6. Acrobat X uses javascript 1.8, I don't know what version of javascript does Acrobat XI use. Any one know? I guess I am looking for any help using the old codes. Thank you.

> One of the easiest and most powerful ways to customize PDF files is by
>   using JavaScript. Based on **JavaScript version 1.5 of ISO-16262
>   (formerly known as ECMAScript)**, JavaScript in Adobe Acrobat software
>   implements objects, methods, and properties that enable you to
>   manipulate PDF files, produce database-driven PDF files, modify the
>   appearance of PDF files, and much more. You can tie Acrobat JavaScript
>   code to a specific PDF document, a page, field, or button within that
>   document, or a field or button within the PDF file, and even to a user
>   action.   JavaScript is particularly useful for XML forms. JavaScript
>   enables automated forms handling, Web and database communication,
>   commenting, and user-interface capabilities. PDF files created with
>   Acrobat and Adobe LiveCycle tools allow data to be extracted as XML
>   into custom schemas. Applications written in Java and other languages
>   easily integrate Acrobat with Web services using Simple Object Access
>   Protocol (SOAP).   Beginning with Acrobat 7, there have been extensive
>   improvements to the JavaScript functionality. There is now support for
>   multimedia, improved printing control, controlling layers, 3D support,
>   and more.   **Acrobat X**   Developing Acrobat applications using
>   JavaScript   Adobe Acrobat X SDK now supports JavaScript that conforms
>   to the standards of **SpiderMonkey 1.8 JavaScript engine**. This release
>   introduces new APIs, such as for adding Signature support for emerging
>   PAdES ETSI ESI standard and for reading files into a stream. In
>   addition, a few APIs have been deprecated. The updated Acrobat X user
>   interface also impacts some of the existing JavaScript APIs.   For
>   more information, visit the JavaScript Support page

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are looking up the airport code and trying to find the city, or the other way around.  Let's assume you're looking up the airport code.

You have your data which you split into array of arrays.  Let's say you're searching for the city with airport code 'YYZ'

```js
const str = `ADL ADELAIDE, AU
AMS AMSTERDAM, NL
ATL ATLANTA, GA
BJS BEIJING, CN
BKK BANGKOK, TH
BLQ BOLOGNA, IT
BNE BRISBANE, AU
BOS BOSTON, MA
BWI BALTIMORE, MD
BWN BRUNEI, BN
CAN GUANGZHOU, CN
CLE CLEVELAND, OH
CLT CHARLOTTE, NC
CMH COLUMBUS, OH
CPH COPENHAGEN, DK
CPT CAPE TOWN, ZA
DCA WASHINGTON, DC
DEL DELHI, IN
DEN DENVER, CO
DFW FORT WORTH, TX
DLC DALIAN, CN
DRS DRESDEN, DE
DTW DETROIT, MI
EWR NEWARK, NJ
FLL FT. LAUDERDALE
FMO MUNSTER, DE
FRA FRANKFURT, DE
GUM GUAM, GU
HAM HAMBURG, DE
HGH HANGZHOU, CN
HKG HONG KONG, HK
HND HANEDA, JP
HNL HONOLULU, HI
IAD WASHINGTON, DC
IAH HOUSTON, TX
ICN INCHEON, KR
JED JEDDAH, SA
JFK NEW YORK, NY
KEF REYKJAVIK, IS
KUL KUALA LUMPUR,MY
LAS LAS VEGAS, NV
LAX LOS ANGELES , CA
LCK COLUMBUS, OH
LGA NEW YORK, NY
LHE LAHORE, PK
LHR LONDON, UK
LIS LISBON, PT
MCO ORLANDO, FL
MDW CHICAGO, IL
MEM MEMPHIS, TN
MIA MIAMI, FL
MNL MANILA, PH
MSP MINNEAPOLIS, MN
MSY NEW ORLEANS, LA
MUC MUNICH, DE
MXP MILAN, IT
NAN NADI, FJ
NRT NARITA, JP
OAK OAKLAND, CA
ORD CHICAGO, IL
PDX PORTLAND, OR
PEK BEIJING, CN
PHL PHILADELPHIA,PA
PHX PHOENIX, AZ
PIT PITTSBURGH, PA
PVG SHANGHAI, CN
RGN YANGON, MM
RUH RIYADH, SA
SAN SAN DIEGO, CA
SAT SAN ANTONIO, TX
SEA SEATTLE, WA
SFO SAN FRANCISCO
SGN HOCHIMINH CITY
SIN SINGAPORE, SG
STL ST. LOUIS, MO
SZX SHENZHEN, CN
TPA TAMPA, FL
TPE TAIPEI, TW
YUL MONTREAL, CA
YVR VANCOUVER, CA
YYZ TORONTO, CA`

const result = str.split("\n").map(function (e) { return e.split("\t"); });

let searchCode = "YYZ";
let city = result.find(function (a) { return a[0] == searchCode; });
// city should now hold the array ["YYZ", "TORONTO, CA"]
console.log(city[1]);
```

The "find" function locates the element in the outer array that has an inner array[0] element equaling in this case 'YYZ'.  Then, we take the [1] element from that, which gives us TORONTO, CA.

I'm pretty sure that the .find method will be implemented in your version of JS since the .map function was there.  But in case it's not, you can use [Mozilla's polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Polyfill) to make it work.

Comment: Hi, James. Yes that is my purpose, search for the code and returned some details. I found that Acrobat Javascript use version 1.8, which should be equivalent to ES5 (2009), map() is in ES5. find() is in ES6 (2015). I've tried find() and it PDF Debugger, it returned below. Any other alternative that works  for ES5? 
'code'
var array1 = [5, 12, 8, 130, 44];
// returned 5,12,8,130,44

var found = array1.find(function(element) {
  return element > 10 });
// returned below
SyntaxError: return not in function
1:Console:Exec
undefined

Comment: Check the last sentence of my answer!  Copy the mozilla polyfill to the top of your JS code, it should allow you to use Array.find.

Comment: I think I probably work with 1D array such as ["YYZ TORONTO, CA"], the search only the beginning 3 letters, do you see this direction works?

Comment: Hi, James Polyfill opens the door, let me do some more research on how to add it to PDF javascript. Sure will post some more questions here. Thank you.

Comment: Hi James, did some googling and got confused on how to implement polyfill snippet into acrobat. Do I add the snippet as a function, or do I put it somewhere else? acrobat has something called snippet runner but it confused me further more.